# Getting Google results in Java? Need help!

Tags: java, search, search-engine

Right now, I'm trying to get the results from Google in Java, by searching for a term. I'm using a desktop program, not an applet.
That in itself isn't complicated. but then Google gave me a 403 error. Anyways, I added referrer and User Agent and then it worked.

Now, my problem is that I don't get the results page from Google. Instead, I get their script which gets the results page.

My code right now simply uses a GET request on "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + Dork;
Then it outputs each line.
Here is what I get when I run my program:

`<.!doctype html><.head><.title>dork - Google Search<./title><.script>window.google={kEI:"9myaS-Date).getTime()}}};try{}catch(u){}window.google.jsrt_kill=1;
align:center}#logo{display:block;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:103px;height:37px;
<./ script><./div>`

Lots of stuff like that. I shortened it (A LOT) and put in dots to fit it here.

So my big question is:
How do I turn this whole mess into the nice results page I get when searching Google with a browser?

Any help would be seriously appreciated, and I really need the answer fast.
Also, please keep in mind that I do NOT want to use Google's API for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "please keep in mind that I do NOT want to use Google's API for this." you really shouldn't be surprised that a company makes it hard to access their data when you circumvent the methods they produce for exposing the data

Comment: what I really wonder is why you don't want to use *rhino* js interpreter already included in **JVM** to use google ajax api that is really clearer and safer.

Comment: Out of interest, what information or type of search result are you trying to access that is not available via the ajax api?

Answer (score 2):

Jack is right, take a look at the Google [AJAX APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch). If you want nicely formatted results, brush up on your html and css.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I already said that I did not want to use the Google API.
One of the reasons is that it returns a maximum of 32 (I think) results per dork, and I need to retrieve many hundred results.